# How can I read pathnames in a file line by line, and apply pushd to each pathname?

Tags: bash

I have a file `/tmp/pathnames` where each line is a pathname to a dir.

```
/tmp/my dir1
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3
```

I want to apply the command `pushd` to each line in the file, so that I can have those pathnames in the dir stack of the current shell.

Here is a bash script for that purpose:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat /tmp/pathnames | while read pathname; do
    pushd "$pathname"
done
```

But it doesn't work as I expected, i.e. no stack of dirs is created for my current shell.

Even if I run the commands in the script in the shell directly with `source`, it still does not work.

I wonder why and how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is the array empty after the while loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272698/65304)

Comment: It's the same reason that variable changes aren't preserved when you pipe to a `while read` loop, and the same solution fixes it.

Comment: Giles' solution in the link is to include the command after the whole pipeline inside the last part of the pipeline, while in my script there is no statement after the whole pipeline. @Barmar

Comment: You don't need a pipeline at all. Just use file redirection: `< /tmp/pathnames`

Comment: Run the script directly will not change the dirs stack of the current shell. Is it possible to run the script without `source` it in the current shell? @Barmar

Comment: No. A child process can't change the directories of the parent process. You need to use `source` to make the script run in the original shell process.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I put the pathname to the script file in `PATH`, and I want to invoke the script without specifying its pathname. If I have to run it by `source`, is it possible to reuse the pathname in `PATH`?

Comment: `source` searches `PATH` by default. If you turn off the `sourcepath` option it won't.

Comment: @Barmar Is there any variable used in my original command, which can't be passed out of the while command in a subshell? I miss to see what I need to pass out.

Comment: You need to pass out the directory stack, which is per-process just like variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the same issue as [Why is the array empty after the while loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272698/why-is-the-array-empty-after-the-while-loop) i.e. that (regardless of whether you `source` it or not), the `pushd` is occurring in a different subshell.

Contrast

```
$ cat pathnames | while read pathname; do pushd "$pathname"; dirs -v; done
/tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/my dir1
 1  ~
/tmp/dir2 /tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/dir2
 1  /tmp/my dir1
 2  ~
/tmp/dir3 /tmp/dir2 /tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/dir3
 1  /tmp/dir2
 2  /tmp/my dir1
 3  ~
$
$ dirs -v
 0  ~
```

with

```
$ while read pathname; do pushd "$pathname"; dirs -v; done < pathnames
/tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/my dir1
 1  ~
/tmp/dir2 /tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/dir2
 1  /tmp/my dir1
 2  ~
/tmp/dir3 /tmp/dir2 /tmp/my dir1 ~
 0  /tmp/dir3
 1  /tmp/dir2
 2  /tmp/my dir1
 3  ~
$
$ dirs -v
 0  /tmp/dir3
 1  /tmp/dir2
 2  /tmp/my dir1
 3  ~
$
```