# Can different bash shell processes share the same stack for `dirs`?

Tags: bash

As far as I know different bash shell processes have different stacks for `dirs -v`. Is it possible to make different bash shell processes to share the same stack? Thanks.

If it can simplify the problem, I don't very care about the order of the pathnames in the stack.

Comment: In reference to your [recent questions on dirs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416608/117549), do you mean: initially at startup, or in a continuously updated way?

Comment: I am fine with either automatically updating periodically, or manually updating by running some command

Comment: My best idea would be to save $DIRSTACK out to a temp file, and have the other shells read it in. Not sure how to handle coordination of that file, though -- which shell "wins"?

Comment: Do you mean the problem is how to synchronize the multiple writes by different shells into the shared file?

Comment: Shell 1 does a pushd and writes to the file; if shell 2 doesn’t read the file before doing its own pushd, who wins?

Comment: They can both append their pathnames to the shared file. I am not very picky about broadcasting the change to the file to every shell immediately. Just periodical update by some daemon is good